# Is it possible write documentation for TestCafe tests using JSDocs?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, jsdoc, testcafe

We would like to generate a living documentation for our team's TestCafe testing framework.
Instead of having separate wiki / separate document to maintain info about the framework, we're exploring option like JSDocs.

The JSDoc templates looks something like below:

```
/**
 * Represents a book.
 * @constructor
 * @param {string} title - The title of the book.
 * @param {string} author - The author of the book.
 */
```

So how to make them more meaningful for documenting our TestCafe tests?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test cases are function calls. JsDoc is not built to document function calls. It is primarily built to document classes, methods, and property declarations, not invocations.

One of the approaches would be to extract your test case code to a separate function and document it. For instance:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `My fixture`
    .page `http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example/`;

test('Test a book', async t => {
    test_a_book(t, 'title', 'author');
});

/**
 * Represents a book.
 * @param {string} title - The title of the book.
 * @param {string} author - The author of the book.
 */
async function test_a_book(t, title, author) {
    await t
        .typeText('#title', title)
        .typeText('#author', author)
        .click('#submit-button')
        .takeScreenshot({
            path:     'books/book.png',
            fullPage: true
        });
}
```

You can also extract your test case logic to a [Page Model](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/concepts/page-model.html) where you can document everything.

Also, you can define the function invocation as a @property or create a custom @tag, but JsDoc does not produce nice-looking documentation for these workarounds.

Comment: How to implement what? Once you created a page model, you can document its members as you would do with any other JS code using regular JsDoc functionality.